# Who is this character from Episode 1: Phantom Menace?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, the-phantom-menace

[image]

I watched The Phantom Menace almost a year ago when I spotted this, and I have just found the picture to prove what I found.

When I was watching - towards the end of the film - where everyone gathers around, I noticed a character (centre left) that I didn't recognise.

I was wondering as to some insight as to who and why this person was here? He seems to be dressed in Jedi robes. Could he have been intended as a stand-in for Mace Windu?

Comment: "I watched the phantom menace almost a year ago and found the picture to prove it" - you don't need a picture to prove it, I believe that you watched the Phantom Menace. Nobody would lie about that.

Comment: Why do you assume that it's supposed to be Mace Windu?

Comment: @Moogle - I've reworded the question to be a bit more open. I do think he has a point given the jedi-looking robes. It's also quite common for stand-ins to end up in the final cut of a movie by accident.

Comment: I was going to say that actually.   They do appear to be Jedi robes except for the white scarf affair around his neck.   Perhaps he is a Naboo dignitary wearing ceremonial regalia that happens to resemble Jedi wear.   The Naboo were known for pompous flamboyant clothing.

Comment: @Moogle: There's what, three black people in the entire Galaxy Far Far Away? If you see a black guy, you've got a one-in-three chance it's Windu, one-in-three that it's Lando, and one-in-three it's this guy.

Comment: @GarthmanGman the "white scarf affair" is actually under his robes. This matches Mace Windu's outfit. http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20071230055326/starwars/images/f/fc/Mace_Windu.jpg

Comment: @Moogle - sure they would lie. The watching gives a noble martyr aura of suffering.... so you have incentive to gain the aura yet spare yourself the pain

Comment: @Moogle Looking at that picture, it looks *exactly* like Mace Windu's robes, just showing a bit more of the "white scarf". It does look like a stand-in for him.

Comment: younger obi wan has similar robes: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_-yeKJGNIgvA/SFpvLsO-X6I/AAAAAAAAHpM/LsbwMKyQQho/S700/ObiWanKenobi.jpg
(although interestingly from EP2 onwards it is different)

Comment: @JamesSheridan - What about the Naboo head of security guy?

Comment: @Richard: Okay, you got me. Four. There are four black men in the whole *Star Wars* galaxy.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - The Voice of Darth is a black guy, as was one of the ewoks; http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140701233106/starwars/images/8/83/Star_Wars_Ewok_actor_Tony_Cox.jpg

Comment: @Richard: I must have forgotten the scenes where Darth Vader's voice appeared onscreen.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - I could argue the same about David Prowse. Lucas clearly hates west-country accents; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YSm9DDxQv8E

Comment: @Moogle stand ins for actors are usually used in place of the real actors when things like the lighting are being adjusted, so they usually need to have the same coloring (skin, hair) as the actor and be about the same height. They also do occasionally fill in for the real actors in wide shots like this, so if you see someone who superficially looks like Windu, it could be WIndu (being played in that scene by a stand-in).

Comment: Now that the Prequel-era EU is flushed out, we can confidently say that this is Wace Mindu, a Jedi Knight who was often mistaken for Master Windu.

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty convincing. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Comment: This question could benefit greatly from a freehand red circle.

Comment: Given that the same scene has some "standmaidens" (people who don't play handmaidens in the rest of the movie dressed in the yellow handmaiden dress), it's clearly a pickup shot where they either couldn't get or didn't bother to get the same actors, so they used stand-ins. Thus, that guy is probably meant to be Mace Windu.

Answer (score 30):

### It's Mace Windu (probably)

Out of universe, this is almost certainly a [stand-in actor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-in) for Mace Windu/Samuel Jackson. The final scenes were filmed in England and it looks like they weren't able to get Samuel Jackson to fly over just to appear in a background scene. The plan, presumably was to CGI his face onto Fake-Mace's body later, but they either forgot or just plain decided that no-one would notice.

Note the fact that Real-Mace (Jackson) is wearing identical robes in the **very next scene** just a few seconds later.

[image]

The [script](http://www.yodajeff.com/scripts/episode1/) also backs this up, albeit there may be *another* Jedi Master that we don't know about that happens to enjoy dressing up like Mace Windu.

> The main ramp of the cruiser is lowered as OBI-WAN and CAPTAIN PANAKA
>   lead the VICEROY and HIS ASSISTANT toward the ship. The GRAND
>   CHANCELLOR PALPATINE and SEVERAL REPUBLIC GUARDS descend the walkway,
>   **followed by YODA and SEVERAL OTHER JEDI MASTERS.**

---

The [Star Wars Phantom Menace Storybook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace_Movie_Storybook) seems to agree.

[image]

Comment: “there may be another Jedi Master that we don't know about that dresses like Mace Windu” — Mace Wannabe. Always shows up where Windu is like fifteen minutes later in the same outfit. It’s pretty sad. Tragically threw himself out of a lower window when Windu died but, typically, only managed to break his legs.

Comment: I like the fact that on some forums they refer to him as "Fakes Windu".

Comment: In the VHS Widescreen version, you still see him coming down the ramp but the scene pictured (where he walks behind Palpatine) is missing.

Answer (score 11):

The most comprehensive list of black Jedi (that is,  Jedi who are black not as google assumes Dark Jedi) I could find is [here](http://www.answers.com/Q/Why_is_mace_windu_the_only_black_jedi).
Reproduced as of October 2014 :

- **Stass Allie (Epsiode II/III)**
- Koffi Arana (Purge)
- Jolee Bindo (Knights of the Old Republic)
- Dace Diath (Tales of the Jedi)
- Dorak (Knights of the Old Republic)
- Eon (Clone Wars material)
- Possibly the Jedi Exile (Kotor II)
- **Adi Gallia (Episode I)**
- Bala Nisi (Knights of the Old Republic Comic Series)
- Possibly Jaden Korr (Jedi Knight: Jedi Academy)
- Qu Rahn (Dark Forces: Jedi Knight)
- Possibly Revan (Knights of the Old Republic)
- **Mace Windu (Episodes I-III)**

I've highlighted the ones who feature in a live-action film. None of these fit the bill.

I can't find a list of characters from that scene (49 - Naboo Celebration? ) as this may not be a Jedi.

The other possibility is that this is Samuel L Jackson's stunt double,  but I couldn't trace who that was either.

So add it stands I can't find out who that character or actor is.

---

I may have found our man, Mark Anthony Newman:

[image: Mark Anthony Newman in Aliens 3]

The above picture comes from a [blog](http://weyland-yutaniarchives.blogspot.co.uk/2012_05_01_archive.html) that seems to be piecing together the prisoners in Alien 3, who is also one of the stuntmen in Phantom Menace. I feel like he bears a strong resemblance to the person, pictured in the question.

So I believe he is meant to be Mace Windu OR a Jedi Extra.

Comment: Stass Alli is a woman, as is Adi Gallia

Comment: @Richard yes,  which is why none of the highlighted characters fit these bill. Adi Gallia is also female.

Comment: For the record, for most of Samuel Jackson's career, he's had a bald **white** stunt double. It's really noticeable in *The Other Guys*, but usually the wide-shots don't pick it up. So that option seems unlikely.

Comment: His costume closely matches Mace Windu's, and he's standing among other council members. It's gotta be a stand-in or something.

Comment: @omegacron that just looks like generic Jedi garb. I wouldn't want to make those assumptions.

Comment: You could be right. When we first saw Stass Allie most of us swore up and down it was a different actress or stand-in for Adi Gallia. And we were wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I believe that's the voice actor of Jar-Jar just getting a cameo

Comment: Do you have anything that would support that?

Comment: He does look similar, but the only cameo for Ahmed Best is in Episode 2 - as [Achk Med-Beq](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Achk_Med-Beq)

Comment: And on further reflection, most production images from Episode 1 [show Ahmed Best with a crew cut](http://www.blueharvest.net/images/prequel/making/making-jarjar4.jpg), not a bald head. So its unlikely to be him. **But good guess!**

Comment: I would have thought that Jar Jar's voice actor would have deliberately avoided ever showing his face again. Guy has to be in the Witness Protection Program by now.

Comment: I'm 99% certain that it's not Ahmed Best; http://www.endorsystem.com/AchkMed-Beq2.jpg

Comment: @JamesSheridan Give the devil his due: that actor played Jar-Jar perfectly.  The character was a blight released upon the Earth, but the voice was an absolutely perfect reflection of the character.  This is a case of a bad thing being done very, very well.  :P